# Check if memcache connection exists using PHP?

Tags: php, connection, memcached

According to php.net, [`memcache_connect()` should return `TRUE` on success or `FALSE` on failure](http://php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php). Therefore, I thought the following code should work even if I change my cache server address to a non-existent address, but it didn't:

```
    $memcache=memcache_connect('myCacheServer.com', 11211);

    if($memcache){
        $this->connect=$memcache;
    }
    else{
        $memcache=memcache_connect('localhost', 11211);
        $this->connect=$memcache;
    }
```

Here's the error message I get:

```
Message: memcache_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary 
failure in name resolution
```

Does anyone know how else I can set up this simple boolean?

Comment: The address still needs to be valid. Try **http://google.com**. The server should try to connect but will not find the memcache server and return FALSE. Might not work though depending on how the domain handles the request.

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't work? $memcache will be true or false - what should $this->connect be? Are you expecting an object, or boolean?  (Note that there is a better way I'll post in an answer, but not sure why the above "dopesn't work")

Comment: @donutdan4114 I want this code to handle the case if the address isn't valid. For example, if the server goes down. If that happens, I'd like to resort to caching on the localhost.

Comment: @Robbie `$this->connect` isn't the problem, i can get rid of that and still the `memcache_connect()` if the address isn't valid.

Comment: That message is displayed on screen? You can hide it with @ before the memcache_connect and it still should return false.

Comment: yes i'm using Codeigniter and these message get displayed on screen after a very long timeout (30sec, like you said). Is there anyway to shorten the timeout?

Comment: To meet your needs, your simplest option (the one I use) is to fall back to file caching. Even if you shorten the timeout, say to 0.5 seconds, that's still a long time to keep a PHP script in suspense.

Comment: First, check to make sure the host is valid: http://in2.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php

Answer (score 1):

As per comment, not sure why the above doesn't work, but there is a much better way of handling this.

If "myCacheServer.com" can't be connected to, then it may take up to 30 seconds each time to timeout. Then after the timeout, you'll fall back to local host - but not much point running memcached if you need to wait 30 seconds each time.

I'd recommend putting the server in a config file, or driving based off a known value - something like

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'localhost') ) !== false) {
    define('MEMCAHCED_SERVER', 'localhost');
    define('MEMCAHCED_PORT', '11211');
} else {
    // assume live - alwways have live as the fallback
    define('MEMCAHCED_SERVER', 'myCacheHost.com');
    define('MEMCAHCED_PORT', '11211');
}

$memcache=memcache_connect(MEMCAHCED_SERVER, MEMCAHCED_PORT);   

// Set the status to true or false.
$this->connect=$memcache;
```

Then, to meet your needs (if you expect the remote server to not be available) I would store this fact in a file on the server. It bit unsualy  but will save you time.

```
// Before calling memcache connect
if (file_exists(MyFlagFile) and filemtime(MyFlagFile) > time() - 600) {
     // Do Not Use Memcached as it failed within hte last 5 minutes
} else {
     // Try to use memcached again

     if (!$memcache) {
         // Write a file to the server with the time, stopping more tries for the next 5 minutes
         file_put_contents(MyFlagFile, 'Failed again');
     }
 }
```

Comment: i see so basically a single user could trigger the rewriting of the config file such that subsequent users (5 min later) would be spared the long timeout?

Comment: That's the idea. Not an "ideal" situation, but it'll be a lot faster (milliseconds) than waiting for the timeout each time. rewriting config is one option (not one I'd propose, but it'll work). I'd suggest just flagging the cache is working or not, and take alternative actions if not.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from [php.net's Memcache documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.connect.php#106786) that partially works. Meaning, the errors displayed to the user are suppressed but you still have to wait for a long timeout if the cache server doesn't exist.

Here's my code for this:

```
    $host='myCacheServer.com';
    $port=11211;
    $memcache = new Memcache();
    $memcache->addServer($host, $port);
    $stats = @$memcache->getExtendedStats();
    $available = (bool) $stats["$host:$port"];
    if ($available && @$memcache->connect($host, $port)){
            $this->connect=$memcache;
           // echo 'true';
    }

    else{
            $host='localhost';
            $memcache->addServer($host, $port);
            $this->connect=$memcache;
            //echo 'false';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code for check connection

```
function checkConnection()
{
    try {
        $client = $this->initClient();
        $data = @$client->getVersion();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $data = false;
    }
    return !empty($data);
}
```